# Drawing a cross on an image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

**Context**: I am performing Object Localisation and wanting to implement an Inhibition of Return mechanism (i.e. drawing a black cross on the image where the **red** bounding box is after a `trigger` action.)

**Problem**: I do not know how to accurately scale the bounding box (**red**) in relation to the original input (`init_input`). If this scaling is understood, then the black cross should be accurately placed in the middle of the red bounding box.

My current code for this function is as follows:

```
def IoR(b, init_input, prev_coord):
    """
    Inhibition-of-Return mechanism.

    Marks the region of the image covered by
    the bounding box with a black cross.

    :param b:
        The current bounding box represented as [x1, y1, x2, y2].

    :param init_input:
        The initial input volume of the current episode.

    :param prev_coord:
        The previous state's bounding box coordinates (x1, y1, x2, y2)
    """
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = prev_coord
    width = 12
    x_mid = (b[2] + b[0]) // 2
    y_mid = (b[3] + b[1]) // 2

    # Define vertical rectangle coordinates
    ver_x1 = int(((x_mid) * IMG_SIZE / (x2 - x1)) - width)
    ver_x2 = int(((x_mid) * IMG_SIZE / (x2 - x1)) + width)
    ver_y1 = int((b[1]) * IMG_SIZE / (y2 - y1))
    ver_y2 = int((b[3]) * IMG_SIZE / (y2 - y1))

    # Define horizontal rectangle coordinates
    hor_x1 = int((b[0]) * IMG_SIZE / (x2 - x1))
    hor_x2 = int((b[2]) * IMG_SIZE / (x2 - x1))
    hor_y1 = int(((y_mid) * IMG_SIZE / (y2 - y1)) - width)
    hor_y2 = int(((y_mid) * IMG_SIZE / (y2 - y1)) + width)

    # Draw vertical rectangle
    cv2.rectangle(init_input, (ver_x1, ver_y1), (ver_x2, ver_y2), (0, 0, 0), -1)

    # Draw horizontal rectangle
    cv2.rectangle(init_input, (hor_x1, hor_y1), (hor_x2, hor_y2), (0, 0, 0), -1)
```

**The desired effect can be seen below:**

[image: Desired]

**Note:** I believe the complexity in this problem arises due to the image being resized (to 224, 224, 3) each time I take an action (and consequently move onto the next state). Therefore, the "anchor" to determine the scaling must be extracted from the previous states scaling, which is shown in the following code:

```
def next_state(init_input, b_prime, g):
    """
    Returns the observable region of the next state.

    Formats the next state's observable region, defined
    by b_prime, to be of dimension (224, 224, 3). Adding 16
    additional pixels of context around the original bounding box.
    The ground truth box must be reformatted according to the
    new observable region.

    IMG_SIZE = 224

    :param init_input:
        The initial input volume of the current episode.

    :param b_prime:
        The subsequent state's bounding box.

    :param g: (init_g)
        The initial ground truth box of the target object.
    """

    # Determine the pixel coordinates of the observable region for the following state
    context_pixels = 16
    x1 = max(b_prime[0] - context_pixels, 0)
    y1 = max(b_prime[1] - context_pixels, 0)
    x2 = min(b_prime[2] + context_pixels, IMG_SIZE)
    y2 = min(b_prime[3] + context_pixels, IMG_SIZE)

    # Determine observable region
    observable_region = cv2.resize(init_input[y1:y2, x1:x2], (224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    # Resize ground truth box
    g[0] = int((g[0] - x1) * IMG_SIZE / (x2 - x1))  # x1
    g[1] = int((g[1] - y1) * IMG_SIZE / (y2 - y1))  # y1
    g[2] = int((g[2] - x1) * IMG_SIZE / (x2 - x1))  # x2
    g[3] = int((g[3] - y1) * IMG_SIZE / (y2 - y1))  # y2

    return observable_region, g, (b_prime[0], b_prime[1], b_prime[2], b_prime[3])
```

### Explanation:

There is a state `t` in which the agent is predicting the location of the target object. The target object has a ground truth box (yellow in image, dotted in sketch), and the agent's current "localising box" is the red bounding box. Say, at state `t` the agent decides it is best to move right. Consequently, the bounding box is moved to the right, and then the next state, `t'` is determined by adding an additional 16 pixels of context around the red bounding box, cropping the **original** image with respect to this boundary, and then upscaling the cropped image back to 224, 224 in dimensions.

Say the agent is now confident that its prediction is accurate, so it chooses the `trigger` action. This basically means, end the current target object's localisation episode and place a black cross on where the agent predicted the object was (i.e. in the middle of the red bounding box). Now, since the current state is zoomed in after being cropped following the previous action, the bounding box must be re-scaled with respect to the normal/original/initial image and then the black cross can be drawn accurately onto the image.

In the context of my problem, the first rescaling between states is working perfectly well (the second code in this post). However, scaling back to normal and drawing the black cross is what I cannot seem to get my head around.

Here is an image which hopefully helps the explanation:

[image: Sketch example]

Here is the output of my current solution (please click the image to zoom in):

[image: Image example]

Comment: I think you want `x_mid = (b[2] + b[0]) // 2` rather than minus. Likewise for `y_mid`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you! I have updated the post in regard to your response.

Comment: There are a lot of things you're not showing. What is IMG_SIZE ? How do you call the IoR function ?

Comment: @Sunreef `IMG_SIZE = 224`, the dimensions of the image. IoR is called with the bounding box `[x1, y1, x2, y2]` of the region in **red**. `init_input` is the original (224, 224, 3) image. i.e. `init_input = np.copy(init_region)`

Comment: The issue is a scaling problem. I believe I need to keep track of a reference point, which is my next approach to figure out how to implement that.

Comment: It looks like a scaling problem to me too. Can you describe why you are doing scaling operations within the function? Are the bounding box co-ordinates corresponding to the scaled or unscaled values?

I think that you might be scaling when some coordinates are already scaled.

Can you update the question after printing the values of `b` and `prev_coord`?

Comment: Can you also look at the ground truth box before and after scaling?
Your updated images seem to be a bit confusing. If you can add one image with initial size, initial ground truth box, final size, final ground truth box - then it will become a bit more clear

Comment: @doodhwala I have updated the post with a (hopefully) understandable explanation of the process. I will continue working on it over the next few hours and update if need be. In regard to your answer, I don't believe I am rescaling with respect to an image, rather the red bounding box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to save the coordinate globally instead of using a bunch of upscale/downscale. They give me headache and there might be loss of precision due to rounding.

That is, every time you detect something, you convert it to global (original image) coordinate first. I have written a small demo here, imitating your detection and `trigger` behavior.

Initial detection:
[image]

Zoomed in, another detection:
[image]

Zoomed in, another detection:
[image]

Zoomed in, another detection:
[image]

Zoomed back to original scale, with the detection box in the correct location
[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

IMG_SIZE = 224

im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('lena.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im = cv2.resize(im, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))

# Your detector results
detected_region = [
    [(10, 20)   , (80, 100)],
    [(50, 0)    , (220, 190)],
    [(100, 143)  , (180, 200)],
    [(110, 45)  , (180, 150)]
]

# Global states
x_scale = 1.0
y_scale = 1.0
x_shift = 0
y_shift = 0

x1, y1 = 0, 0
x2, y2 = IMG_SIZE-1, IMG_SIZE-1
for region in detected_region:
    # Detection
    x_scale = IMG_SIZE / (x2-x1)
    y_scale = IMG_SIZE / (y2-y1)
    x_shift = x1
    y_shift = y1

    cur_im = cv2.resize(im[y1:y2, x1:x2], (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))

    # Assuming the detector return these results
    cv2.rectangle(cur_im, region[0], region[1], (255))

    plt.imshow(cur_im)
    plt.show()

    # Zooming in, using part of your code
    context_pixels = 16
    x1 = max(region[0][0] - context_pixels, 0) / x_scale + x_shift
    y1 = max(region[0][1] - context_pixels, 0) / y_scale + y_shift
    x2 = min(region[1][0] + context_pixels, IMG_SIZE) / x_scale + x_shift
    y2 = min(region[1][1] + context_pixels, IMG_SIZE) / y_scale + y_shift

    x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)


# Assuming the detector confirm its choice here
print('Confirmed detection: ', x1, y1, x2, y2)

# This time no padding
x1 = detected_region[-1][0][0] / x_scale + x_shift
y1 = detected_region[-1][0][1] / y_scale + y_shift
x2 = detected_region[-1][1][0] / x_scale + x_shift
y2 = detected_region[-1][1][1] / y_scale + y_shift
x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)

cv2.rectangle(im, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0))
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

This also prevents resizing on a resized image which might create more artifacts and worsen the detector's performance.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. By storing the changes "globally" and using your re-scaling method it now works perfectly! Thanks again, I will follow what you said in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a point `(x, y)` in a `500x500` image. Let it be `(100, 200)`.
After scaling it to a different size, say `250x250` - the correct way to scale it would be to just look at the current co-ordinate and do `new_coord = old_coord * NEW_SIZE/OLD_SIZE`.

Thus, `(100,200)` will be transformed to `(50,100)`

If you replace your scaling using `x2-x1` and use a simpler rescaling formula, it should fix your problem.

Update: `NEW_SIZE` and `OLD_SIZE` may be different for the two co-ordinates based on the shape of the original image and final image, if they are rectangular and not square.